Visualization of STL files in Mathematica
I have an STL file that I want to make pretty from within Mathematica.  The STL file should show a series of cuboids, each touching the next on one face and there are 6 of these cuboids.  I simply want to colour each cube differently so that I can more easily differentiate between the different layers for a diagram in a report.
When I Import the STL file it shows the following:

This is a good start but I would like to 1) remove the lines showing the triangular faces and 2) colour each cuboid differently.  How do I do this?
Any help would be much appreciated (Link to the stl file...
STL file )
Cheers!

Where exactly do you have a problem? Generally, you should be able to use Import to import an STL file, which will be represented as a MeshRegion in Mathematica.

@Domen please see updated post

“there doesn't seem to be an attachment button” upload to somewhere like google drive and paste the link.

@AsukaMinato see edited post, cheers.

It is possible to recolor the mesh created from the stl, but it is a bit involved.
If your only purpose is to make a nice figure of a laminate, how about this:
cube[{bottom_, top_}, color_] := {color, 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, bottom}, {10, 10, top}]}

With[{stack = 
   cube[{h[#1], h[#1 + 1]}, c[# + 1]] & /@ Range[0, 3] /. {h[0] -> 0, 
     h[5] -> 10}, sliders = Sequence @@ controls
  },
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[stack],
  sliders
  ]
 ]

where
controls = 
 Join[{{{h[1], 1}, h[0], h[2]}, {{h[2], 2}, h[1], h[3]}, {{h[3], 3}, 
     h[2], h[4]}, {{h[4], 4}, h[3], h[5]}} /. {h[0] -> 0, 
    h[5] -> 10}, {c[#], RandomColor[]} & /@ Range[1, 4]]


